# Is TwoLineListItem clickable? How can I click it?

Tags: android

I've got an activity populated by TwoLineListItems, and I'd like to be able to click them to go to another activity and show a more in-depth view of the information associated with the TwoLineListItem. Do I just use a standard OnClickListener and declare each TwoLineItemListener as clickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TwoLineListItems` are intended for use in `ListViews`. In order to implement a clickHandler for a listView you would override the `onListItemClick` method.

If you are not using a ListView, and your TwoLineListItem is a child of a different layout, I would recommend using a simple Linear or RelativeLayout instead.

Comment: Actually, to get my results to display properly, I have a TableLayout, and for each result a new TableRow is added, then the TwoLineListItem is added to the TableRow, then the TextViews are added to the TwoLineListItem. My results need to beshown in such a way that some text is bigger and above other text, and this was the easiest way I could think of.